# A pendulum in an elevator - looking upside down

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

If I have a pendulum connected to the floor of an elevator by a string, and the elevator is falling in an acceleration greater than g - can I just "rotate" the system and look at it as a regular pendulum connected to the ceiling moving in a period of sqrt((a-g)/l)?
[image]

Comment: For the accelerating cart, just change the coordinate system to match the acceleration vector (g+a) and you are good to go. You could angle the ceiling and floor so someone inside can't tell what is happening, except everything is heavier and magnitude(g+a) determines the period.

Answer (score 2):

In your comment you asked a second (closely related) question about a cart accelerating horizontally.

Both these problems can be solved by transforming the frame of reference to a new frame in which the  net acceleration is vertically down. The transformation you want to use is a rotation of the axes; the new "apparent gravity" is the vector sum of the two accelerations.

So for the vertical case the new acceleration is indeed

$$g'=g-a$$

While for the cart it is

$$g'=\sqrt{g^2+a^2}$$

You then compute the period of the pendulum in the usual way.

Incidentally you can also solve this problem by using d'Alembert fictitious forces in an accelerating frame of reference. Briefly, in an accelerating frame of reference an object of mass $m$ appears to have an additional force $-ma$ acting on it. Once you have taken that additional force into account you can solve the equations of motion normally.